# Target clicked element in Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

In Vue.js how do you target/detect the clicked element to perform a basic toggle class?

I've written this which toggles successfully but when you click an `a` the class is applied to to all `li`'s

HTML

```
  <ul id="app" class="projects">
    <li v-bind:class="dyClass"><a href="" v-on:click.prevent.stop="show = !show">Project A</a></li>
    <li v-bind:class="dyClass"><a href="" v-on:click.prevent.stop="show = !show">Project B</a></li>
    <li v-bind:class="dyClass"><a href="" v-on:click.prevent.stop="show = !show">Project C</a></li>
    <li v-bind:class="dyClass"><a href="" v-on:click.prevent.stop="show = !show">Project D</a></li>   </ul>
```

JS

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      show: false,
    },
    computed: {
      dyClass: function() {
        return {
          show: this.show
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

I'm new to Vue.

EDIT.

I managed to get it working with a mix of help from below, but I dont seem to be able to get the toggle effect.

```
  <ul id="app" class="projects">
    <li :class="{show:selected == 1}">
      <a href="" @click.prevent.stop="selected = 1" >Exposure</a>
    </li>
    <li :class="{show:selected == 2}">
      <a href="" @click.prevent.stop="selected = 2" >Exposure</a>
    </li>
    <li :class="{show:selected == 3}">
      <a href="" @click.prevent.stop="selected = 3" >Exposure</a>
    </li>        
  </ul>
```

and

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selected: false,
    }
  });
```

Comment: You are binding the same class the every click event. So, if any item is clicked it toggles the current state of your class (which every item has). You need to target each list item through a unique ID.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass element to function (`$event`):

`:click=dyClass($event)` Then in computed:

```
dyClass: function(event) {
    event.target.toggleClass('whatever')
}
```

Comment: I get an undefined 'toggleClass' error with this. If there is a better way to achieve the same result, I'm all ears

Comment: .toggleClass() is a jQuery method.  For vanilla JS you can use event.target.classList.toggle('whatever')

Answer (score 3):

As i understand you have some `li` items and you want to add an active class when a specific `li` gets clicked.

**Solution:**

the "html" part:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul class="projects">
    <li v-for="project in projects"
        :key="project.id"
        :class="{ active: project.id === activeProjectId }"
        @click="activeProjectId = project.id"
    >
      <a href="#">{{ project.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The "vue" part

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        projects: [
     { id: 1, name: 'Project A' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Project B' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Project C' },
     { id: 4, name: 'Project D' },
    ],
    activeProjectId: 1
  },

})
```

Then add some css to the 'active' class.

For more, [See the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/375602/)

Comment: Sorry for delay. This works great..  I do feel like it could be simpler though? I did come up with something. Going to post.